# sum the checked check boxes value and show in another field

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am fetching data from database table (test) using select box and a search button in html table along check box in each row,

I want to add the charges of checked check boxes and sow the price in price field.

When I enter the discount value in (discount) field, this will calculate discount from price and show the final price in the (after discount) field
and time should be sum and show in time field.

I also want that the checked check boxes rows should remain in view after another search because the checked check boxes rows do not remain in the view after another search. and after another search and checking the checking the price should be added to price same for discount same for after discount and time

After all I want to submit this data in another table (register).

[image: test table: fetching data]
[image: register table : inserting data]
[image: view]

```
<div class ="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="table1">
        <tr>
            <form method='post'>
                <td><select name="group" style="width:100%;" required="">
                        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>select .....</option>
                        <option>General</option>
                        <option>HEAMATOLOGY</option>
                        <option>BIO CHEMISTRY</option>
                        <option>DIABEIC PROFILE</option>
                        <option>SEROLOGY</option>
                        <option>CBC</option>
                        <option>BLOOD EXAMINATION</option>
                        <option>ARTHRITIS PROFILE</option>
                        <option>URINE EXAMINATION PROFILE</option>
                        <option>LIPID PROFILE</option>
                        <option>KIDNEY FUNCTION TEST</option>
                        <option>LIVER FUNCTION TEST </option>
                        <option>OLT</option>
                        <option>URINE EXAMINATION</option>
                        <option>SEMEN ANALYSIS</option>
                        <option>PLEURAL FLUID/SYNOVIAL FLUID/C.S.FULID</option>
                        <option>PBF</option>
                        <option>STOOL EXAMINATION </option>
                        <option>MICROBIOLOGY</option>
                        <option>ELECTROLYTES TEST</option>
                        <option>HEAMOGRAM</option>
                        <option>SEMEN EXAMINATION</option>
                    </select></td>
                <td><input type='submit' name="search" id="search" value="search" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"></td>
            </form>
        </tr> 
    </table>
</div>
<?php 
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","laboratory");
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $search=$_POST['group'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM test WHERE test_cata LIKE '$search' ";
    $db=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    while ($run=mysqli_fetch_array($db)) {
        $name=$run['test_name'];
        $time=$run['test_time'];
        $charge=$run['test_charge'];
?>

<table border="1" class ="table-responsive" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $name;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $time;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $charge;?></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="choice" id="choice" /></td>
    </tr>

<?php } 
} ?>

</table>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="decimal">Price (₦) <span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>
        </div> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"  name="total" id="total" placeholder=" Price" value="0" readonly="" >   
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="int">Discount (%) </label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="discount" id="discount" placeholder="Discount eg:(10)" value="0">        
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="decimal">After Discount <span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>
        </div> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="total_price" readonly="" id="total_price" placeholder="Total Price" value="0">      
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="decimal">Total Time <span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>
        </div> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="total_time" readonly="" id="total_time" placeholder="Total Time" value="0">   
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Book"/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-warning">
<a href="../dashboard/dashboard.php" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>

</form>
</div>
```

Comment: unless you want to get the totals after submitting the form, you will need to use client-side, ie. javascript. And it will be harder due to having duplicated `id`s -> `id="choice"`, that are created in a loop.

Comment: ishti: please don't edit the question to make it harder to read; my edit was intended to help, if I've not done enough to help then please [edit] to improve.

Comment: The loop that is creating the checkboxes is generating invalid HTML. IDs must be unique. Either don't use an ID (it is not required after all), or add a counter to your loop and use it in the ID (e.g. `id="choice<?php echo $i;?>"`). Anyway, your question is not easily answerable on SO because there are several things need fixing. I suggest that you break it into several question, and ask only one thing in each question.